# How can a slice with -1 step starts from -2?

Tags: python-3.x

With a string of length n, want to get a copy of reversed first (n-1) characters.
There are several ways to achieve it :

```py
>>> a = 'abc'
>>> a[::-1][1:]
'ba'
>>> a[:-1][::-1]
'ba'
>>> a[len(a)-2::-1]
'ba'
```

but when it comes to single character string,

```py
>>> b = 'a'
>>> b[::-1][1:]
''
>>> b[:-1][::-1]
''
>>> b[len(b)-2::-1]
'a'
>>> b[len(b)-3::-1]
''
```

I know `len(b) - 2` equals -1, and `[-1]` points to the last item.
But why it should be start from len(b)-3 to get a empty string?

I tried the slice of `[len(b)::-1], and thought it would raise an error, and get the expected result unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use a slice of `len(a)-2::-1` to begin with. Since you want to start from the second-last character, `-2` should be the starting index instead:

```
>>> a = 'abc'
>>> a[-2::-1]
'ba'
>>> a = 'a'
>>> a[-2::-1]
''
```